# Vuejs error, Invalid prop: type check failed for prop. Expected Date, got Number with value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a very simple code that was supposed to get me started on learning Vue but I somehow still managed to bug it. I have the following code:

```
export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data() {
      return {
          model: this.value,
          dateConfig: {
              format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
              useCurrent: true,
              firstDate: this.minDate,
              secondDate: this.maxDate
          },
      }
  },
  props: {
    firstDate: {type: Date, required: false},
    secondDate: {type: Date, required: false}
  }
}
```

And after importing this file and trying to use it in another page as follows:

```
<my-component v-bind:first-date="12-12-2019" v-bind:second-date="31-11-2011"></my-component>
```

This returns the following two errors:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "firstDate". Expected Date, got Number with value -2019.

and

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "secondDate". Expected Date, got Number with value -1991.

While the first error makes a bit of sense (even though I don't know why it is happening), the second error shocks me as I don't have '1991' anywhere. Could someone please explain to me why this is happening as I adhered to the format the date should be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you pass in an expression in props javascript. From your example: 11 - 31 - 2011 === -1991.

I recommend reading the documentation for understanding props:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props

You can fix it as follows:

```html
<my-component
  v-bind:first-date="new Date('12-12-2019')"
  v-bind:second-date="new Date('31-11-2011')"
></my-component>
```

But I would pass the data as a string. But in such cases, do not forget to change the type of the passed parameter in the component. «Date» change to «String».

I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand about `props` and `Date`.

"12-12-2019" is `String`, but not `Date`.
So you can't get this prop as Date in child component.

And if you want pass pure string prop, also  you should not use v-bind.

```
<my-component
   first-date="12-12-2019"
   second-date="31-11-2011"
></my-component>
```

For more information, when you use v-bind, vue recognized its value as script.
let's assume that there's a data value firstDateValue: "12-12-2019"

```
v-bind:first-date="firstDateValue" // String "12-12-2019"
```

```
first-date="firstDateValue" // also String "firstDateValue"
```

And `v-bind:first-date` can be simplified as `:first-date`.

```
export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data() {
      return {
          model: this.value,
          dateConfig: {
              format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
              useCurrent: true,
              firstDate: this.minDate,
              secondDate: this.maxDate
          },
      }
  },
  props: {
    firstDate: {type: String, required: false},
    secondDate: {type: String, required: false}
  }
}

...

<my-component
   first-date="12-12-2019"
   second-date="31-11-2011"
></my-component>
```

Comment: Ty for highlighting the mistake but I still can't seem to pass a `Date`. Even without quotes it says that it is a String.

Comment: You need to change `Date` as `String` in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a variable with type `Date` because the Props of `MyComponent` required this type

See in Documentation [Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props)

```html
<template>
    <MyComponent :first-date="firstDate" :second-date="secondDate" />
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
   data: () => ({
      firstDate: new Date('12-12-2019'),
      secondDate: new Date('31-11-2011')
   })
}
</script>
```