# VueJs: Invalid prop:Expected Boolean, got Undefined

Tags: vuejs2

When using a component i got two errors

1-

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "premium" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property

2-

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "premium".
>   Expected Boolean, got Undefined

Here is my Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>eCommerce</title>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="app">
        <product :premium='premium'></product>
      </div>




      <script src="public/plugins/bootstrap-4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
      <script src="public/js/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="public/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
Vue.component('product', {
      props: {
        premium: {
          type: Boolean,
          required: true
        }
      },
      template: `
        <div class="container">
           <p>{{ premium }}</p>
        </div>
    `,
      data() {
        return {
          cart: 0,
          color: "white"
        }
      },
      methods: {
        addToCart() {
          return this.cart++
        },

      }

    }) //component

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',

});
```

Comment: I don't see 'premium' prop in new Vue declaration in a data section that's why VueJS got you these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you didn't define your data property, just add new one to your instance, see this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   // i set true because your component requires Boolean type
   premium: true
  }
});
```

Comment: It's good practice to keep a component self-defined (isolated, loos coupling) rather than define its property globally in app (strong dependency). Thus a definition should be done inside component, e.g via _default_.

Answer (score 3):

Issues here are two:

1. required property is referenced but not defined
2. invalid property type

#### define the required prop

You need to **define an initial value**, since property is *required*.
This is best done using a *default*:

```js
Vue.component('product', { 
  props: {
     premium: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
     }
  },
```

See also [[Vue warn]: Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur)

#### bind a value with valid type

You are [dynamically binding][1] (denoted by colon `:` as shortened *v-bind* prefix) a *JavaScript expression* `premium` to the boolean property.

Assuming there is no variable of this name `premium` defined, it will evaluate to JavaScript value `Undefined` instead of required valid boolean values `false` or `true`. Thus the warnings.

Try binding it to a **constant** with either *dynamic binding* or simple *static binding* like:

```
<product premium="true"></product>
```

See also [Vuejs error, Invalid prop: type check failed for prop. Expected Date, got Number with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052070/vuejs-error-invalid-prop-type-check-failed-for-prop-expected-date-got-number)

#### further reading on props

- [Official docs: passing Boolean to prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-a-Boolean)
- [How to Use Props in Vue: The Ultimate Guide (with Examples)](https://michaelnthiessen.com/vue-props-ultimate-guide)